# VB.NET Application store

Tags: vb.net

I want to make an windows forms application that lets you download my applications. Every application will contain a name,description,released,current version,logo. How can I do that?

Comment: Very broad question and a lot more info is required.  How are you going to distribute your installer/downloader application.  How are you hosting your applications for download.  What sort of technology are you planning?  Why not just a web site for initial downloads with a self updating application

Answer (score 0):

This is a broad question. You have to be specific. If you want somebody to do a program for you, you need to go to another place.
Because you want to connect with the internet for download, I advise using a web application. Easy to download and upload.